# I tried npm run build in astro, and it won't work for some reason

Tags: npm, terminal, build, astrojs

I got some errors when i try to npm run build my project in Astro.

This is the error:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eofg.png)

It fails every time when it tries to build the static encryptions.

Can anyone help me?

I tried to look for the error but did not end up finding 'em.

Comment: Can you post your package.json and Astro config? Or a repo you can share.

Comment: package.json:
{
  "name": "spaced-astro",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    "start": "astro dev",
    "build": "astro build",
    "preview": "astro preview",
    "astro": "astro"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "astro": "^3.6.0"
  }
}

Astro.config:
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
    site: "https://bas-bulckaen.be",
    base: "/",
    image: {
        domains: ["localhost"]
    }
});

Comment: Not sure if related to your specific error, but your site should have `https://` in front. You also shouldn't need to specify localhost in your remote image domains. Otherwise try deleting node_modules and your package lock file and re-installing again e.g. `npm install`.